# ORDER BY values while returning from CASE{} in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to order the results returning from CASE conditioned. But it is throwing error with this message:

```
Variable `strength` not defined (line 8, column 104 (offset: 243))
"RETURN {strength:CASE WHEN p.strength IS NULL THEN r.strength ELSE p.strength*r.strength END} ORDER BY strength DESC LIMIT 3"
```

Looking at the error message I understand that strength is not identified.

How can I do Order by along with this case functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with `CASE`. The problem is that an `ORDER BY` clause must refer to identifiers in the `RETURN` clause, but your `RETURN` clause  is returning a map without an identifier.

In this (simplified snippet), the map is given the identifier `res`, and the `ORDER BY` uses that identifier:

```
RETURN {strength: r.strength * CASE WHEN p.strength IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE p.strength END} AS res
ORDER BY res.strength DESC
LIMIT 3;
```